# How to set position of scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table and give horizontal scrollbar for it. But my table out of window vertical screen, so if I want to see my horizontal scrollbar I have to scroll to bottom of screen. How can I fix the position of horizontal scrollbar always see on screen?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SfYu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HdUa.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code **i.e.** [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe `table { overflow: auto }` will work